# Counterexample for LTL - CTL equivalence

Tags: linear-temporal-logic, temporal-logic

I have to find an example of a model where the LTL-formula $F G p \wedge F q$ is valid and the CTL-formula $EF AG p \wedge AF q$ is not valid. I found this example, but I'm not completely sure whether it's correct:

[image]

Comment: Your example is incorrect, since the LTL formula doesn't hold: in the computation $s_0,s_1,s_2,s_3^\omega$ the formula $FGp$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Hmm yes, you're right. Do you know an example in which it does hold and the CTL-formula doesn't? Or would it be easier to find an example in which the CTL-formula does hold and the LTL-formula doesn't hold?

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question about this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions here and here and adjust your question accordingly, for example by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. Can you figure out what it is that you don't understand that's stopping you from determining whether your answer is correct?

Comment: The actual problem is the fact that I don't really understand the difference between the A (all paths) in CTL and a normal LTL-formula which also holds for all paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following model: you have 3 states, $s_0,s_1,s_2$ with the transitions: $s_0\to s_0$, $s_0\to s_1$, $s_1\to s_2$ and $s_2\to s_2$ and the labels are $L(s_0)=\{p,q\}$, $L(s_1)=\emptyset$ and $L(s_2)=p$.

Then, every computation starts with $q$, so $Fq$ holds, and every infinite computation eventually gets stuck in $s_2$, or it is $s_0^\omega$, and both satisfy $FGp$, so the LTL formula holds.

However, it never holds that $AFq$, so the CTL formula does not hold.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I see now. Is there some trick that helps you find such differences between LTL and CTL or is it just plane reasoning?

Comment: As with most problems, there is no "trick", just reasoning and some experience. Conceptually, it is possible to find such an example algorithmically: let $\phi$ be an LTL formula and $\psi$ be a CTL formula, then you can construct the CTL* formula $A\phi\wedge \neg \psi$, and then use CTL* satisfiabilityto find a model for the formula. But the complexity of this algorithm is terrible - 2EXPTIME, so it's not suited for solving exercises.

Comment: Thank you! I will practice more then :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have one more little question: I don't quite understand why $AF q$ never holds? The computation starts with q, so at that point $AF q$ is satisfied? Or not?

Comment: Hmm. I read your CTL formula as $EF(AGp\wedge AFq)$, in which case my example is fine. But if it's intended as $(EFAGp)\wedge AFq$, then my answer is incorrect, and I think that there is no (non-empty) model that will have the desired property - obviously $AFq$ has to hold, by the LTL formula, and if $EFAGp$ doesn't hold, then along every path, every state has a path from it in which $AGp$ doesn't hold, which means we can construct a path that does not satisfy $FGp$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much! In that case I understand what happened. I indeed read the formula as $(EF AG p) \wedge AF q$.